# RedisTemplate not fetching data in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, jedis

Having a Separate Config file for Redis Config.

```
package com.xyz.abc.webapp.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.redis.repository.configuration.EnableRedisRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer;

@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories
public class RedisConfig {


  @Bean
  public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    return new JedisConnectionFactory();
  }

  /**
   * client for redis operations.
   * @return RedisTemplate
   */
  @Bean()
  public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    return template;
  }

}
```

`redisTemplate.keys("*")` returning empty set.

I don't get what is the problem.

**But works fine when Bean are decalared inside Component.**

Answer (score 6):

Worked after setting

> template.setDefaultSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());

```
 @Bean()
  public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    template.setDefaultSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    return template;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! After hours of digging and pulling my hair out, I finally stumbled on this.